# Release Date of New version of WSO2 appmanager(1.2.0)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-iot

I was working on App manager, while accessing the store from my device the User interface was not responsive. But I have heard that all these bugs are resolved in the latest version. So when could I expect the release of next version. Or alternatively, how can I customize the code so that I could make the store, responsive for accessing through mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

released version of wso2 app manager use bootstrap 2.X version and you can use bootstrap 3.X versions to make it responsive.

Here is the bootstrap update guide: http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/

Comment: I tried to replace bootstrap 2.x with 3.x , but not working...
bootstrap 3.x require JQuery 1.9.0 or above and other JS library is not compatible with that.
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to change spanX to col-<>-X as wel. have you try that out